# Mobilefirst 8.0 - App crashes on Android version 5 below on https call

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, adapter, okhttp

App build on `MobileFirst 8.0` is getting crash on Android `version 5` below while calling `https service` using `adapter`. Same is working on `version 5` and above.

**Below are the logs captured in device logs :**

```
OkHttp ConnectionPool
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:197)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2056)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:435)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

**Please assist if any body has faced the same issue.**

Comment: What is the version of your Android MobileFirst SDK & server. Also what is the version of TLS ?

Comment: 8.0.0 version for Android Mobile First SDK & server.

Comment: Amit, what is the exact build version of your SDK? cordova plugin or native SDK's exact build version? And is it a proper SSL endpoint - or something configured using custom or self -signed certificates?
And what if you switch networks? Data instead of wifi or vice-versa?

Comment: Hi Amit, We tried with the latest MobileFirst sdk on android api <5 ,both the native and cordova apps, but never hit this issue .Provide more clear information as mentioned by Vivin in his comment  above .

Comment: `android:minSdkVersion="16"` `android:targetSdkVersion="23"` and it is a proper SSL endpoint.
Issue occurs due to SSL Pining check only before service call.

Comment: @Shubha S SSL check crashes APK in android lower version.

Comment: @Amit I tried with API 17 x86 architecture(4.1.1 and 4.2.2) emulator and api 16(htc device) but never seen such error .Are you seeing the issue in any specific device ?Can you share the exact android version architecture where you see the failure ?Also if possible share the sample app using which i can recreate the issue .

Comment: @Amit what feature are you using in mobilefirst for android?

Comment: @Gandhi For calling API using Adapter in mobilefirst.

Comment: @ShubhaS here is the sample apk link https://www.dropbox.com/s/9bnwurcah6mczbo/sampleMobilefirst.apk?dl=0

Comment: Check to see if adding org.apache.http.legacy in your manifest works